# TypeError: __init__() takes X positional arguments but X+1 were given

Tags: python

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        # here we want to make a player, and start making some attributes
        self.player = character(50,50,100, (0,255,0), "Player")
        self.enemy = character(55,200,200, (255,0,0), "Enemy")
        self.alive = [self.player,self.enemy]

class character():    # this will be the class which can make any 
    def __init__(self,x,y,health,colour, name):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.colour = colour
        self.width = 90
        self.height = 50
        self.vel = 0.04
        self.name = name
```

When I try to use or change the colour attribute (of the character) in my Game class, I get an

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

while defining the object `player` as here:

```
self.player = character(50,50,100, (0,255,0), "Player")
```

Why does Python tell me I gave it 6 arguments, when I only gave 5?

Comment: The code you've pasted does _not_ raise that error (not even if you initialize a new `Game`).

Comment: I also cannot replicate the error.

Comment: This error usually occurs when you forget to add the `self` argument to a method - but your code didn't. I don't see any problem with it.

Comment: I do know the empty parenthesis are not needed in the class definition.  Perhaps this could cause the error depending on the python version?

try:   ```class character:```  .....

Comment: What do you mean by "use or change the color attribute"?  Can you show the code you are executing to do that?  Or better yet, give the entire code you are executing that produces the error.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will solve the problem seeing as I cannot replicate the error either way but, Empty brackets are not needed on the class definitions.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # here we want to make a player, and start making some attributes
        self.player = character(50,50,100, (0,255,0), "Player")
        self.enemy = character(55,200,200, (255,0,0), "Enemy")
        self.alive = [self.player,self.enemy]

class character:    # this will be the class which can make any 
    def __init__(self,x,y,health,colour, name):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.colour = colour
        self.width = 90
        self.height = 50
        self.vel = 0.04
        self.name = name
```

Comment: They don't make a difference either way.